# What is the best solution to use a common domain/subdomain with Jekyll on Heroku and other hosting website?

Tags: heroku, dns, jekyll, octopress

I just moved my personal website to Octopress from Drupal. I am hosting it on Heroku and I really don't like the herokuapp.com domain. I already have myname.com domain which I am planning to use with Heroku now for my main website.

The problem is I have some other websites hosted on my hosting service which use databases and other stuff. They were being accessed by project1.myname.com, project2.myname.com etc. I don't want to move them and have a similar subdomain naming thing to access them.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it should be easy to do this with your DNS settings. Simply point the DNS "A" records for "myname.com" and "www.myname.com" to Heroku and leave "project1.myname.com" and "project2.myname.com" pointing to your existing provider.